# How to get filtered data on Google Sheets API with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, filter, google-sheets-api

At the moment I'm able to get data from Google Sheets form a specific sheet and cells range. But I can't find the way to get the data from specifics columns sending also the criteria to get the filtered data with 2 simple conditions.
Is it possible to do this?

I've tried use BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest

```
Sheets sheetsService = getSheetsService();
        FilterCriteria criteriaForC = new FilterCriteria().setCondition(new BooleanCondition().setType("BLANK"));
        FilterCriteria criteriaForD = new FilterCriteria().setCondition(new BooleanCondition().setType("BLANK"));

Request request = new Request().setSetBasicFilter(new SetBasicFilterRequest()
                .setFilter(new BasicFilter()
                        .setRange(new GridRange().setSheetId(733419412))
                        .setCriteria(ImmutableMap.of("2", criteriaForC, "3", criteriaForD))));
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest body = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(ImmutableList.of(request));
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, body).execute();
        response .values();
```

But do not return any data, only fliters the online spreadsheet on the browser.